# Проблемы при использовании Any CPU

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Одной из проблем при компиляции с использованием Any CPU- это то, что если ОС имеет х64 разрядность, а на машине стоят х32 разрядные драйвера, то приложение будет пытаться найти х64 драйвера, которых нет.

Явным примером может служить  OleDb Jet 4.0 для Access.

Решением данной проблемы могут быть следующие:

1)Отказ от Any CPU

2)Требовать пользователя установить необходимые драйвера для своей ОС.

Но можно ли это решить как-нибудь иначе?

Comment: устанавливать нужные драйвера при установке приложения?

Comment: @rdorn, а нельзя сделать, что бы проверились X64, а если их нет, то X32 ?

Comment: не уверен что стандартные обертки .NET это позволят, у них вроде нет параметров отвечающих за выбор драйвера или разрядности, но я глубоко не копал